# CefSharp chromium crashing winforms 32 bit application

Tags: winforms, chromium, cefsharp

Hi All I am new to using CefSharp in my application. I need some help resolving an issue I am facing. I have a 32 bit winforms application and installed version 81 of cefsharp dll's. My server is a 64 bit machine. I redirect from my form to a website (ADP). Sometimes it works and sometimes it crashes with an error like below. I am not able to find what is going on and any help is really . The dll's and my application are in a folder on a server (server1). User login into a terminal server(server2) and access the application from a shortcut on the desktop.  Below is the error.

Windows cannot access the file  for one of the following reasons: there is a problem with the network connection, the disk that the file is stored on, or the storage drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing. Windows closed the program CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess because of this error.

Program: CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess

Faulting application name: CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe, version: 81.3.100.0, time stamp: 0x5ec8803e
Faulting module name: libcef.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5eac9798
Exception code: 0xc0000006
Fault offset: 0x005ae118
Faulting process id: 0x4a34
Faulting application start time: 0x01d674c9b69143f4
Faulting application path: \serverpath\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe

Comment: Are you running the application over the network? That's not recommend.

Comment: yes, the application is running over the network. The application is not installed on the server. Should the application run locally on the server? Multiple users from multiple servers are accessing the application. Can you please let me know what is the best way to run the application in order to use the Cefsharp without any issues?

Comment: Is the `CefSettings.CachePath` on the network as well? From memory `Chromium` doesn't like being run over a network.

Comment: I did not specify the cache path anywhere in my application. All I did was added chromiumbrowser onto my form and on pageload calling the chromiumbrowser.load(URL). I am not sure what you are referring to but there is a folder GPUCache created on my server and a file named Index is updated everytime my form is hit. Can you please guide me through how to set this up? I tried to set cefsettings but there is not such cefsettings available for me. I have cefsharpsettings and this object doesn't have any property cachepath.

Comment: Run your application from local disk is my suggestion. If you haven't specified a CachePath then that's not going to help you setting one I don't think.

Comment: Thank You @amaitland . I will try and see if it helps.

Comment: If you wish to persist user data (cookies etc) then you will need to set a CachePath see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#initialize-and-shutdown You can try to see if things improve on the off chance it was trying to write something in your app folder. Running from local disk would still be my suggestion though.

Comment: Updated the application to run locally and it is working fine for now. Thank you for the help.